# Who was present when Rick Jones said "Who in this room has been dead before"?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, episode-identification

I'm looking for the comic where Rick Jones said "Who in this room has been dead before?" I want to know who all was present.  I know Dr Strange and Wong were present. Anyone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Incredible Hulk #399](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_399), The quote isn't exactly right but they've got the gist. Rick Jones is trying bring his lover, Marlo Chandler back to life. In the scene you're referring to, he asks Doctor Strange and his manservant Wong (**the only other people present**) whether they've ever died. He later approaches Henry Pym and Reed Richards to see if they can help, but he is rebuffed at every turn.

This being a comic, you'll not be in the least bit surprised that he is...

> ...eventually successful. Let's face it, she's no [Uncle Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death).

[image]

Comment: *Note to self: don't bother reading comics. They're silly.*